# Copy object to objectCopy

Tags: object, copy

I try to copy object to objectCopy. How to do that ?

```
Object obj = new Object();

org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = null; 

Object objCopy = Util.copyObject(obj, orb);
```

> Orb is null, that is why this operation is NullPointerException.

Please tell me how to "obj" copy to "objCopy". I prefer using **"Util.copyObject()"**. It is here problem with "orb". I have no idea how to normally inicialization this.

Comment: Who knows how to inicialize variable "orb". Come on. This is easy :)

Comment: org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = ??  Please about sugesstions

Comment: `org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init`?

Comment: org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(); It's still NullPointerException. I gave another object (not obj) and was the same. It's orb is reason. Now I have: org.omg.CORBA.ORB orb = org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(); It's wrong.